# its shows format isn't support msg ,when i try to share file

Tags: java, android

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intentShareFile.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

intentShareFile.setType("application/*");

intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content:/"+path));

Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "share");

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

i am using this code to send a file using intent component... but it shows error msg ...

Comment: Post the complete error message and format the code.

Comment: there is no error msg .. when i install the application and then i try to share the file then it shows toast msg ..

Comment: Okay, well that toast message sounds like an error, could you post that?  We also don't know what `path` is.  See how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Don't use: `Uri.parse("content:/"+path)`

Try use: `FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".FileProvider", path)`

Comment: What type of file? Image, pdf or doc...? Why you use setType("application/*")?